# which data types- foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have one little question:

```
foreach(range(1, 10) as $numbers)
    {
       echo $numbers. " ";
    }
```

When we use foreach loop, which data types are elements of $numbers? Or foreach loop served to show products of array?

Comment: You mean you want to get the types per `$numbers`?

Comment: int's http://ideone.com/f3Ru8S

Comment: Thanks, nogad, i think so, but didn t sure :)

Comment: well then test it, like i did :-)

Comment: Depends on the datatype of the elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

They are integers (int) by default. If you have the code like this,

```
var_dump(range(0,10));
```

Then the output will be:

```
array(9) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> int(12) [2]=> int(13) [3]=> int(14) [4]=> int(15) [5]=> int(16) [6]=> int(17) [7]=> int(18) [8]=> int(19) }
```

But if the parameters of the range variable are floats,

```
var_dump(range(0.5,10.5));
```

Then the output will be:

```
array(11) { [0]=> float(0.5) [1]=> float(1.5) [2]=> float(2.5) [3]=> float(3.5) [4]=> float(4.5) [5]=> float(5.5) [6]=> float(6.5) [7]=> float(7.5) [8]=> float(8.5) [9]=> float(9.5) [10]=> float(10.5) }
```

So the answer is, **it depends on the two parameter inputs you give to the range function.**

Comment: Could also be string datatype: range() will work with ASCII characters as well - `var_dump(range('H', 'O'));`

Comment: Yes. Not only that.  I forgot that